# Using Constraint Layout but still layout gets messed up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create a layout for my recycler view. I thought the best would be using a constraint layout for the activity. It renders correctly in the preview window but gets distorted while running the application. I tried using constraint layout before but I got the same problem please help. I posted both the code and image file of the layout

this is after running the application[image: second file]

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/levelback">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userface"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/player2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.004"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_angry" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="212dp"
        android:text="@string/player2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.014" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usedesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="descryption"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.324"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You forgot to put the left/start constrain on the `userName TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userface"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/player2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_angry" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="player2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userface"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usedesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="descryption"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userface"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/username" />
```

Put it inside `ConstraintLayout`.
Change your Strings and manipulate with margins if you need to.